# ß inside \path{} of hyperref-package

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

I want to insert a file path containing a `ß`. Therefore I want to use the `\path{}`-command from the `hyperref`-package to set it correctly (i.e. not to replace all `\` by `/`). However, my file path contains a German "umlaut" and so I get a wrong result.

How can I tell `hyperref`, to read the `ß` as a symbol and not as its two-byte UTF-8 representative?

My code example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % language
\usepackage{hyperref}                   % include links

\begin{document}
Test ä, ö, ü und ß.

\path{hier entlang... ß}
\end{document}
```

The output of `Test ä, ö, ü und ß.` works well, but inside the `\path`-environment the `ß` is replaced by its two bytes.

As I read, `hyperref` seems to read the input bytewise. How to tell `hyperref` to read "UTF-8" instead? I also checked that my code file itself is saved in UTF-8 properly.

Comment: What's the deal with `hyphsubst`? Doesn't seem to play a role here. There is also no need for `\inputenc` and you might want to try without `\fontenc`. Once I remove those packages your MWE compiles just fine for me – using LuaLaTeX, I might add.

Comment: @Ingmar does it also generate the correct output? I only get the right output if I use a unicode aware engine (I tested `lualatex`) and got rid of `inputenc`, `fontenc` and `hyphsubst` (which did not know `ngerman-x-latest`). I think `\path` will have issues with any multibyte char when running under `pdflatex`.

Comment: If you want to use non-ASCII characters you should probably commit to a modern, Unicode-aware engine like LuaTeX, yes.

Comment: `\path` is not a command from hyperref but from url, and yes it has problems with non-ascii chars and even more with utf8.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: If I comment out hyperref, then I get an error, so I thought, \path comes from hyperref.

Answer (score 3):

Let's add some support for the UTF-8 prefix `0xC3`. Other prefixes can be added in a similar way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% less ugly ß
\usepackage{url}

\AddToHook{cmd/Url@OT1encSpecials/after}{\do\^^c3{\checknextCthree}}
\AddToHook{cmd/Url@T1encSpecials/after}{\do\^^c3{\checknextCthree}}
\newcommand{\checknextCthree}[1]{\mbox{\UrlFont\csname u8:\string^^c3\string#1\endcsname}}

\begin{document}

Test ä, ö, ü und ß.

\path{hier entlang... ß}

\end{document}
```

I removed all inessential bits. Two additions are necessary in order to also support OT1.

[image]

Comment: is `\UrlFont` really necessary? I have not checked url.sty but out of memory I recall it sets up the math font to match the desired text font which is put in place as well. (so the text font in the hbox matches the font for other chars)

Answer (score 1):

Not a real solution but perhaps a circumvention for Windows only: Legacy DOS names still work in general up to Windows 11. "8.3 filename" convention is using the first six letters (in caps, without spaces) and append `~1`, `~2`, `~3`... plus `.[file extension]` counting upwards if multiple options exist. `my file.tex` gets `MYFILE~1.TEX` You can get these names in command line terminal with `dir /x`.

So if your primary target is Windows and the ß occurs after more than 6 characters, this could be a somehow dirty trick.

Answer (score 1):

`url` package (loaded by `hyperref`) provides `\path` as a variant of its `\url`.  The way `\url` works is that it will detokenize its argument via usage of `\meaning`.  This destroys the `pdflatex` (inputenc, now default in LaTeX) support for UTF-8 characters which relies on making some bytes active.  Retokenizing the whole thing via `\scantokens` looks dangerous as after all the whole point is to handle special stuff such as `%`,  and one would need to find the right time to it.  As a less intrusive method let's add (I probably did not find the best entry-point, there is a `\Url@HyperHook` which perhaps could be considered, I took `\Url@actpercent` as entry point.

You have to explicitly enumerate all characters you want to allow.
I did not add interface for a comma separated input of many such characters, simply the main command for one character at a time.

Proof of concept:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed with recent LaTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % language
\usepackage{hyperref}                   % include links

\makeatletter
\newcommand\userrescuethischarforurlcommand[1]{%
   \expandafter\user@rescuethischar\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}{\hbox{#1}}%
}
\def\user@rescuethischar#1#2{%
   \g@addto@macro\Url@actpercent{\Url@Edit\Url@String{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\userrescuethischarforurlcommand{ß}
\begin{document}
Test ä, ö, ü und ß.

\path{hier entlang... ß}
\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

The `\hbox` is as work-around to LaTeX not accepting some character commands in math mode, and `\url` uses underneath math mode.

Extended example:

```
\userrescuethischarforurlcommand{ß}
\userrescuethischarforurlcommand{ä}
\userrescuethischarforurlcommand{ö}
\userrescuethischarforurlcommand{ü}
\begin{document}
Test ä, ö, ü und ß.

\path{hier entlang... äöüß}
\end{document}
```

[image: extended example]

Comment: @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685030/293669) is better (although more technically challenging to extend by layman for UTF-8 with 3 or 4 bytes).